# how to pass object into another array object

Tags: arrays, vue.js, axios

**please help me to pass the object into another array thank you vuejs**

 how to pass object into another array object

> ```
> import axios from 'axios';
>
>     export default {
>     data() {
>           return{
>               scholars: [],
>               slp: []
>            
>             }
>      },
>      methods:{
>       loadScholar(){
>        axios.get('api/scholar')
>            .then(({ data }) =>{
>              this.scholars = data
>            }
>          )
>       },
>
>       async loadapi(){
>         const {data} = await axios.get('api/ronin')
>         const promises = []
>
>         Object.keys(data).forEach((item) => {
>           promises.push(
>             axios.get('https://axiegame/game-api/clients/'+data[item].api+'/items/1')
>             .then((res) => res.data)
>           )
>         })
>         this.slp = await Promise.all(promises)
>      
>       },
>      
>      },
>      created(){
>        this.loadScholar();
>        this.loadapi();
>      
>      },
>     }
> ```

> 

this is json output on gameapi and i want to get the total and pass in scholars array

> > 
>
> ```
> `"success": true,
> "client_id": "0x0cc5d2800ea2a76c8811b7d2d2091b09359378f9",
> "item_id": 1,
> "total": 1778,
> `
> ```
>
> > json data on my rest api
>
> ```
> `"data": [
> {
> "ronin": "ronin:0cc5d2800ea2a76c8811b7d2d2091b09359378f9",
> "scholar": "rodny"
> }
> ],`
> ```

the output i want

> > 
>
> ```
>  `"data": [
> {
> "ronin": "ronin:0cc5d2800ea2a76c8811b7d2d2091b09359378f9",
> "scholar": "rodny",
> "total": "1778"
> }
> ],`
> ```

Comment: there are three apis being hit here, to get scholars, ronin, and perhaps an item for a client?? can you expand more on what youre trying to do?

Comment: the second api is from my laravel controller loop and get the 0x0cc5d2800ea2a76c8811b7d2d2091b09359378f9/client_id and pass it in another api and get the total


        Object.keys(data).forEach((item) => {
          promises.push(
            axios.get('https://lunacia.skymavis.com/game-api/clients/'+data[item].api+'/items/1')
            .then((res) => res.data)
          )
        })
        this.slp = await Promise.all(promises)

Comment: perhaps if you explain to me, as though i was a not-nerdy friend, what youre trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not easy to run loadScholar function, insert data into shcolar, and loadApi to insert total, how about running loadScholar function, then call loadApi to process all the data, and then insert data into shcolar?